# How to dynamically activate categories in main navigation as products are added to the category?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a site where users upload products. When the user uploads a product, they can currently select from about 50 categories.

I would like to have all categories listed in my main navigation, however they won't all have products listed in the category in the early stages of the site. The ones that don't should not be linked and the text would be greyed out.

The part that is confusing is how to manipulate the main nav via a view. All of my views are for specific pages, so I'm not sure how to have a view function that runs prior to each page's view function, sort of like a custom middleware in Node + Express routing.

Or perhaps this is not Djangoic, and there is a better method to achieve this?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Hey, what is the relation between Product and Category models?

Comment: @engin_ipek currently there is no relation, as categories are currently CharFields, but now that I want to do this, my expectation is that I need to give categories and subcategories their own model, and list categories and subcategories under Product with ForeignKey

Comment: Check the answer below, he is quicker than me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a foreign-key relationship from `Product` to `Category` in your models. That being said, you can render a link only if that category has products in it:

**template**:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.product_set.count > 0 %}
        <a href="{% url 'category_detail' category.pk %}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ category.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and if you want to prevent users from accessing the category pages with no product **manually** (e.g. the user enters `example.com/category/xxx` manually), you can add as simple `if` condition before rendering the template:

**views.py**

```
def category_detail_view(request, category_pk):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_pk)
    if category..product_set.count == 0:
        # redirect to a custom page
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, what I'm still confused on is how to expose `categories` to my main template?

Comment: Are you looking for a `ListView` or something like that? it should be the case if you want to show all `category` objects.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is I need. My main template needs access to `categories`, however I don't know how to deliver that to the main template. I have no issue delivering it to other templates individually. Perhaps I need 'ListView' or perhaps a 'Context Processor'? I've Googled around and am more confused than when I started..